# typescript private variables message

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my typescript class I have two private variables. One variable is goping to store a string that I am returning from an API. The other one is a message that I will be displaying to the user. Once the API is completed and will use the return and build the full message. In the response I am setting `this.templatIds` so it will build the message with the correct ids that. But in my popup message its missing the section from the string.

```
export class AgentsGridComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    private templatIds = "";
    private inuseItemMessage = `This Agent is being used by Templates ${this.templatIds} and can't be archived`




this.agentsService.inuseTemplateAgentList(data.item.Id)
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.Value);
                        this.templatIds = response.Value;
                        this.notificationManager.error(inuseItemMessage);
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `templatIds` is not populated at the time that the `inuseItemMessage` is assigned to - they both get assigned at the same time, at the beginning of the constructor. Make the message into a *function* instead, so it can construct the template string from the now-populated `templatIds` on demand.

```
private getInUseMessage = () => `This Agent is being used by Templates ${this.templatIds} and can't be archived`
```

```
this.notificationManager.error(this.getInUseMessage());
```